# How to pass base64 encoded string from android to webview

Tags: javascript, android

I am creating an app which is reading the JPG files from phone and then converting  the image data into base64 encoded string and passing this string into web view, where I will convert this string into an image.

Currently when string data is less than 2 MB then android is successful 
calling my JS method but when data is greater than 2 MB then it fails.

What should I do in this issue. My sample webview JS function is:  **getFileDataFromInterface(fileData)**

Comment: Webview is perfectly able to load image files directly from your device. So i wonder why you would load it. Then convert to base64 and finally offering the base,64 to webview. For what? Only causing troubles as you saw.

Comment: Moreover the subject of your post is wrong as you seem to be able to pass. The problem is passing more than 2MB.

Comment: @greenapps  basically there is different UI for upload dialog and also native image chooser is processing the image (reducing the image size)

Comment: ????? Dont understand a word of this. Please react to the point to what i said.